Deleted faces of an object appear in render
I have a twisty sort of cable like object where I have deleted the faces for part of the end so that I can show something inside.  In the layout view it shows everything as I would like, even in the rendered view mode

however, when I actually render the scene, the faces are replaced on the object

The faces in question were deleted by selecting the object, going into edit mode and face select mode, selecting the desired faces, then pressing "x" for delete and selecting the faces option.
I've checked for orphaned data, recalculated the normals, and checked for hidden objects to no success.
The cable was created by first generating a bundle of cylinders and then using an array curve fit modifier and curve deform modifier.  When I go back to just the bundle (no modifiers) and delete faces it will render the bundle without the faces just fine.
Any ideas on what might be going on are appreciated

Hello, can you share your .blend file through https://blend-exchange.com/ and link it in your question? Until we have it, we'll only be able to make assumptions.

Check if you don't have an object that is invisible in preview but visible in render in your Outliner

I’m voting to close this question because  it's a simple slip up, fixed without needing an answer, and covered before in the archive. (moonboots was on it)

I was removing excess information to reduce file size for sharing and came across the solution.  I had duplicated the cable in question a few times and hidden them for later use, but forgot that they already had the modifiers attached.  I must have hit the wrong hot keys when I was checking for hidden objects.  Thanks very much for the suggestions!

Hello River .. glad you found it !  This is the kind of slip-up that's easy to make, and is rather too localized to be useful to the archive.. it has been covered in various hard-to-find guises before.. so I think we can fairly close this question out. If you disagree, just let us know with an edit. Stripping a file down for sharing often uncovers the problem :)
